# provisional profile is not found for the device

Tags: ios, xcode

I know that it has been asked a thousands of times, but I am struggling 4 hours with every possible sollution I read but still I cannot beta test my app in my device.

Here are the facts:

1) My app is uploaded in the IOS store, so I have created a provisioning profile, app id's and so on. I just now want to test it in my iPhone4, with target iOS 6.0.

2) I added my device UDID in the devices, in my developer account.

3)I set the code signing for debug to my provisioning profile.

4) I plugged in my ios device in the mac and I see that picture.

[image]
As you can see there is no provisioning profile.

5)If I run the app to my ios device (which is listed in the Xcode) I get the error

```
No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version.
```

I tried so many solutions that I found that I cannot even remember all of them. I am following all the steps one by one.
-someone said to log out from developer account
-other said to change deployment target
-other said to change the "edit scheme" to debug.

Can anyone help me? I do not understand what is missing since app is published and I only want to test it in my device. Should I change anything else?

EDIT: I selected the device as Ganee said. Then in my organiser I see the following picture:

[image: Organiser]

If I press refresh, I see "Too few items in team".

So If I remove the provisioning profile, how do I download the new one? I suppose I enter my developer account and press download in the distribution profile under the provisioning tag, right? But is this updated with the selected device?

Here is my picture from the developer account:

[image: Developer account]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the problem was that I had a distribution profile set up, and not a developer. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I think you followed all steps, but still you have to conform the following steps.

- After you added device to developer account, you have to select that device in your provisioning profile.
- Remove old profile from your organiser, download new modified profile and install it on your Mac.
- Please check wether you modified developer/ distribution profile and select it on your xcode.

Hope this will give some clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I remember having similar problem in the past.  I am not sure if yours is similar.  But awhile back when I upgraded my iOS device, it was no longer compatible with the xcode version I was running.  I had to upgrade to the latest version of xcode.  What is Xcode version are you running?

Comment: there is no available update for xcode, so i suppose i do have the latest. ps. i do have xcode 4.5.2 and ios 6.0 on device